# How to select UIImage in storyboard from View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, storyboard, iboutlet

I am currently trying to select a `UIImageView` that I have created in the storyboard in my view controller.

Is there a method equivalent to android's `findViewbyId` in objective c?

Comment: In iOS you'll need to use tags for that. Those can be retrieved with "[viewwithtag](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622429-viewwithtag)"

Comment: The concept differs in iOS. You want to make it an `IBOutlet`. Google it. To make it "select-able", set a `TapgestureRecognizer.  Google it.

Comment: @shallowThought thank you! I'm actually working on animations but I definitely needed to know that for later. My biggest issue with working in iOS is that I do not know the terms for anything making my search for answers difficult. Which is why I've asked such a simple question via SO.

Comment: The concept is same in iOS. You can use viewWithTag:20 method.

Comment: @Airagale: In this case google for ["iOS equivalent to XYAndroid feature"](https://www.google.de/search?q=ios+equivalent+to+findViewbyId&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=oRdRWMzGA4fc8Aex_YSoDA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just [make an IBOutlet](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html) for the imageview?

Then you can just access it by something like

```
self.imageView
```

Where imageView is what you named your outlet.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to iOS from android dev and this is the simplest answer.  This isn't like findViewById for android but it works the same in the end.

I am using [self imageView]; to avoid the warning "Property access results unused - getters should not be used for side effects”

Answer (score 0):

Place a `UIButton` over your `UIImageView`.

Comment: Could you explain how this allows me to manipulate the UIImageView in the view controller?

Comment: If you want to manipulate it you should outlet it, I thought you wanted to detect touch.

Comment: sorry I should have specified.  check out shallowthought's comment on the question- I might try that first before overlaying a button in an area like that.

Answer (score 0):

After creating an IBOutlet as Samantha suggested you will need to add a gesture recogniser to your UIImageView.

I would suggest adding the gesture recognizer in viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singlePress =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewPressed)];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}

- (void)imageViewPressed {
    //Perform imageView action here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the viewWithTag

```
   UIImageView *yourImage = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:20];
```